# Angular - Populate the HTML page with the JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I have the following JSON data but would like to implement the HTML page such that it shows the parent as the header and all the children under the same parent under the content and then follow by the second parent as the header and all the children under the second parent under the content. How would I be able to do so? An example would be the following:

> **Sample 1**
>
> Product 1 - Test Product 1
>
> Product 2 - Test Product 2
>
> **Sample 2**
>
> Product 1 - Test Product 1

```
"sampleList": [
  {
    "parent": "Sample 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "product": "Product 1",
        "name": "Test Product 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": "Sample 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "product": "Product 2",
        "name": "Test Product 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent": "Sample 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "product": "Product 1",
        "name": "Test Product 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you check your JSON? It's duplicate the parent and children key.

Comment: @YongShun Hello yes the JSON is returning in this format where there can be duplicated parent key however the children key will not repeat if the parent key is the same

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it clearly. I mean your JSON schema is duplicating the properties key of "parent" & "children". So now your JSON is an array with a single object. I expect that your JSON should be an array with 3 objects as [this](https://jsonblob.com/950593632185106432).

Comment: Ohh yes you are right the JSON should be an array with 3 objects my apologies I have just made the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With `Array.reduce()` to perform group by `parent` and concatenate array.
2. Create a new array from result 1 with each object element has `parent` and `children` property.

```js
let grouped = this.sampleList.reduce((groups, current) => {
  groups[current.parent] = groups[current.parent] || [];
  groups[current.parent].push(...current.children);
  return groups;
}, Object.create(null));

this.groupedSampleList = Object.keys(grouped).map((key) => ({
  parent: key,
  children: grouped[key],
}));
```

If you use `es2017`, you can work with `Object.entries()` as:

```js
this.groupedSampleList = Object.entries(grouped).map((value) => ({
  parent: value[0],
  children: value[1],
}));
```

```
<div *ngFor="let parent of groupedSampleList">
  <strong>{{ parent.parent }}</strong>
  <div *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
    {{ child.product }} - {{ child.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-spltya?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hello may I seek your help to further understand what is each of the line in the code doing as I am not familiar with Array.reduce() and the usage of the groups[current.parent] and also .push(...current.children)?

Comment: Ya, sure. `reduce()` is aimed for transforming an array to specific type. For this scenario to transform an array to object / key-value pair. `groups` variable is a variable for aggregation. First line `groups[current.parent]` is to check whether the `current`'s `parent` is existed as `key` in `group`. If exist, use the respective key value pair, else create a new key value pair with the value initialized as empty array. Then use the key value pair, `groups[current.parent]` and add every element in `children` into it (`.push(...current.children)`).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation so from my understanding if the object contains three attributes (parent, children, content) for example this approach would not be able to work out since it utilizes a key value pair (parent, children) am I right?

Comment: Ya, as the result of `grouped` is: `{ "Sample 1": [/* Children of Sample 1 */] }`. For the new field content, you need to ammend the logic in `.reduce()` so the result of grouped will be like: `{ "Sample 1": { Content: /* Content Value */, Children: [/* Children of Sample 1*/ ] } }`

Comment: Okay I got it may I seek your help in understanding the part for the `this.groupedSampleList`

Comment: Ya sure, for `groupedSampleList`, `Object.keys(grouped)` is used to iterated each key ("Sample 1" and etc.) and with `.map()` to create a new array with the object same structure as the object structure in original `sampleList`. `Object.entries(grouped)` answer also done the similar job but it is able to iterate and get both key (return index of element) and value (return both `parent` and `children` as an array) together (for the above case, I just need `(value)` only).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242713/discussion-between-nic-and-yong-shun).

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data structure provided contains duplicate keys which is not ideal. Also, parents with the same value have children stored in separate locations. If the format could be improved such that each parent and child are separate items in the list, it can be easily performed iteratively using a ngFor, which allows you to iterate through data. Providing the JSON key will display the needed child elements. I have included an example below. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Reformatted Data:

```
sampleList": 
[
    {
            "parent": "Sample 1",
            "children": [
            {
                    "product": "Product 1",
                    "name": "Test Product 1",
            },
            {
                    "product": "Product 1",
                    "name": "Test Product 1",
            }],
    },
    {
            "parent": "Sample 2",
            "children": [
            {
                    "product": "Product 1",
                    "name": "Test Product 1",
            }]
    }
]
```

```
<li *ngFor="let item of sampleList; index as I;">
    <h3> {{item.parent}} </h3>
    <li *ngFor="let item2 of sampleList[I].children;">
        <div> {{item2.product}} - {{item2.name}}</div>
    </li>
</li>
```

Comment: Hello yes I am aware of the ngFor but is there a way to check since the parent element can be duplicated as seen from the JSON data

Comment: @Nic It cannot be done iteratively unless the data is formatted properly.